# Google Ads API, C#, SOAP request with new oAuth 1.0?

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I'm using Google Ads API for a while and making SOAP API request using the ClientID.
now I learned that Google is adding a oAuth way to communicate with there database.

lets say I have the auth and the secret (or using Anonymous) what I need to do in order to add this information to the SOAP request.

Any info will help.

Thanks !

Comment: Have they already added this ability.  I would simply check their documentation on this feature.

Comment: (A), yes they add the ability. (B) the documentation sucks, I've already spent two days there trying to figure what's what with no luck. I wouldn't ask a question here without trying it first (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdWords API supports OAuth 1.0a, and the .NET library supports it too. An ASP.NET code example is available at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Fcsharp%2Foauth and the documentation on using the library with OAuth is available at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/wiki/UsingOAuth.

Cheers,
Anash P. Oommen

Comment: First of all thanks of the reply. Going over the example here I see there explaining how to use it in a web application on-line (with user interactions) I want to be able to store the user Token and use it when he is off-line to monitor the account etc.

Comment: I just updated the wiki. If you follow the original sequence on the wiki, then once you call the GenerateAccessToken(), you can save user.OAuthProvider.AccessToken and later load it back. Something like:

`(user.OAuthProvider as AdsOAuthNetProvider).AccessToken = new OAuthToken(TokenType.Access, "ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE",
"ACCESS_SECRET_HERE", "CONSUMER_KEY_HERE");`

This way, if you have an alternate way of generating OAuth tokens, then you may do so, you don't have to essentially do all those ASP.NET based dance.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to mention that our primary discussion forum is at http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api?pli=1, and I frequently answer developer questions there, so if you have any followup questions, feel free to ask there and I'll be happy to answer your questions.

Btw, I didn't edit the previous answer because Stackoverflow allows only 2 links for users < 10 reputation points. I just joined Stackoverflow a few minutes back to answer your question :)

Cheers,
Anash

Comment: I was using the community "http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/" for asking question and didn't get any answers there. I'll reopen this question in the "group". P.s. I'll give you "ups" for the answers so you can post more links in the future.

Comment: It is the same thing, just bump the question if you don't see a reply in a couple of days.