# HOW TO oAuth and SOAP?

Tags: c#, soap, oauth, google-ads-api

HELP !
I'm trying to upgrade may program to support the new oAuth that Google uses in the AdWords.
Using my website I'm able to create an accessToken and an accessTokenSecret for my users and store it in my database.

My problem is when I try to make a soap request later with those credentials.

- Which information do I need to save from the website part? so far I save only the accessToken and the accessTokenSecret. is there anything else?
- How do I use the accessToken, accessTokenSecret and what ever else I've saved in order to make a SOAP requests? (please be as "low level" as you can, "just use them in the request header" won't help me).

Some info on my process:

- Not using the Client Library from Google (too much over head, and so far I didn't needed them).
- Using the auto-generated SOAP code using VS2005 WSDL on the services I'm using.
- C# code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

=======================================================================================
As advised, I have extend the GetWebRequest in the following way:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

            String token = "XXXXXXXXXXX";//a valid token - changed for here.
            String secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";//a valid secret - changed for here.
            String consumerKey = "anonymous";
            String consumerSecret = "anonymous";
            String sigMet = "HMAC-SHA1";
            String oauth_timestamp = ((DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks) / (1000 * 10000)).ToString();
            String oauth_nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            Parameter[] paramArray = new Parameter[]{
                                        new Parameter("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey),
                                        new Parameter("oauth_token", token),
                                        new Parameter ("oauth_signature_method", sigMet),
                                        new Parameter ("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp),
                                        new Parameter ("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce)
                                        };

            String oauth_signature = CreateHMACSHA1Signature(
                                        request.Method,
                                        uri,
                                        paramArray,
                                        consumerSecret,
                                        secret
                                        );

            request.Headers.Add(
                            "Authorization: OAuth " +
                            "realm=\"" + "https://www.google.com/" + "\"," +
                            "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + Parameter.EncodeParameterString(consumerKey) + "\"," +
                            "oauth_token=\"" + Parameter.EncodeParameterString(token) + "\"," +
                            "oauth_signature_method=\"" + Parameter.EncodeParameterString(sigMet) + "\"," +
                            "oauth_signature=\"" + Parameter.EncodeParameterString(oauth_signature) + "\"," +
                            "oauth_timestamp=\"" + Parameter.EncodeParameterString(oauth_timestamp) + "\"," +
                            "oauth_nonce=\"" + Parameter.EncodeParameterString(oauth_nonce) + "\""
                        );

            return request;
        }
```

the function `CreateHMACSHA1Signature` is the same one used to with `OAuthGetRequestToken` and `OAuthAuthorizeToken` just fine. but when used with the SOAP I'm getting the following error:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_INVALID @  Service[ServicedAccountService.get]

Any idea why it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUCCESS !!!

I finely found what was wrong, and it was only by a chance.
when creating the signature I've used the `request.method` for the method parameter.
The problem with this is that at this moment the method is "GET" but the SOAP mechanisim will change it to "POST" (so it can pass the SOAP parameters) this cause my signature to not work.

the only fix I needed to do is change:

```
String oauth_signature = CreateHMACSHA1Signature(
    request.Method,
    ...
    )
```

to:

```
String oauth_signature = CreateHMACSHA1Signature(
    "POST",
    ...
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

I've answered this question here in the context of the .NET client library at [Google Ads API, C#, SOAP request with new oAuth 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433227/google-ads-api-c-soap-request-with-new-oauth-1-0/8453257#8453257). But to answer your question in a NoClientLibrary context,

1. You just need the consumer key in addition to OAuth access key and secret.
2. You need to sign the request as if you were requesting a normal OAuth protected resource. Then put the signature in Authorization HTTP header (not the SOAP header) of your SOAP web request. However, getting hold of the underlying HttpWebRequest for a SOAPHttpClientProtocol object is not that straightforward. You need to extend SOAPHttpClientProtocol object, override the protected GetWebRequest method and set your OAuth headers at this stage: Something like:

   ```
   protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri) {
     WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
     string oAuthHeader = SignTheRequestAndGetTheOAuthHeader(request);
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oAuthHeader)) {
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = oAuthHeader;
     }
     return request;
   }
   ```

This also means that you have to manually modify the autogenerated code to change the base class of your stub service classes, something you are not going to enjoy much in the long run. Also, in case you don't know how to normally request an OAuth protected resource, the relevant documentation is at http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor13.

Now, this is something that has been taken care of for you in the .NET client library. The library is not that difficult to use, there are enough wiki articles at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/wiki to guide you. I recommend that you use the .NET client library, but in case you choose not to do so, here's a list of pitfalls you should be aware of when taking the NoClientLibrary route: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/wiki/NoClientLibrary.

I also wanted to mention that AdWords API official discussion forum is at http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api?pli=1, and I frequently answer developer questions there. If you have any followup questions, feel free to ask there and I'll be happy to answer your questions.

Cheers,
Anash

Comment: going over "http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/wiki/NoClientLibrary" I see there is so many explanations there. if only there could be an explanation on how to create the "oAuth" like they explain how to create the "AuthToken" every thing was awesome.

Comment: Hey, taking your advice I'm seem to be able to add my oauth to the request. but I'm getting an OAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_INVALID error, and I can't get to understand why. have any idea? Thanks !

Comment: I'm on vacation right now, but I'll add a NoClientLibrary OAuth version once I am back from vacation.

Comment: FWIW, here's a reference for OAuth http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html. The only difference is that your scope is different for AdWords API.

Comment: If you have done all the signing correct, then OAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_INVALID could be because your scopes don't match. For sandbox, it should be https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords, whereas for production account, it should be https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords.

Comment: I've used the production scope (adwords.google.com/api/adwords.) all the process. thank you a lot for the help. enjoy your vacation (: